# Sharing Configuration Data in GameCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm developing an application where the user can play a short game in which cards are selected randomly from a database.  I would like to use game center to allow the user to upload his/her score in the game to a **Leaderboard** and also to upload an `NSArray` with the locations of the cards in the database.  Sharing the `NSArray` allows other users to play an identical game.

Sharing the score is easy.  How would one share the `NSArray` via `GameCenter`?

Comment: Im not an expert, but I don't think thats possible, but I see your reasoning. You could probably do this with your own server, but still upload the score to game center

Answer (score 1):

There's no uploading NSArray w/ game center. The posted score is of type int64_t.

*However*, if you look at the documentation - You will see that there's also a context (which is also an int64_t) property on the GKScore object. If your data is small, you can pack the location of the cards there, allowing other players to reproduce the initial conditions using that.